# Change post URL for sagepay in Magento

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, opayo

Im integrating sagepay as a payment gateway into my magento installation. There seems to be some issues with the IP address included on the server however ive contacted sagepay and they've asked me to put some test purchases after changing the POST URL to https://test.sagepay.com/showpost/showpost.asp

is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: just to add to this im using the ebizmarts sagepay extention if this makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

A 4020 error is a common error which can be resolved.

You need to ensure the IP is a fixed IP for Server or Direct integrations rather than a dynamic IP (an IP that changes).

If you look in My Sage Pay within Transactions>Invalids you will see the error along with the invalid IP. If the IP is not visible in Invalids you can either:

1. use our Simulator (submit a transaction to Test and if the IP is not detailed in My Sage Pay, you will get a 4020 error and you will be able to see the IP within the [Simulator](https://test.sagepay.com/simulator/)). To register for a Simulator account which is effectively a pre testing account click [here](https://support.sagepay.com/apply/simulator/requestAccount)).
2. you can send a Showpost to Sage Pay so that we can confirm the IP we are receiving your transaction from.

Once you know the IP that you are posting your transactions from, enter the IP within My Sage Pay, Settings>Valid IPs.

If you are unable to add additional IPs within My Sage Pay chek the Subnet Mask is not overlapping.
You only need to enter one of the IP addresses if you are entering the Subnet Mask as 255.255.255.248 as this means any IP address which is the same barr the last three digits will be accepted subject to the last 3 digits being less than 248. Example:

IP address 217.194.220.205 and Subnet Mask 255.255.255.248 registered on the Sage Pay account will therefore accept any IP address which starts '217.194.220.' and has the last three digits between '000' to '248'. You therefore do not need to enter the other four IP addresses as you have already covered these within the IP address and Subnet Mask already entered.

If you need any further help from Sage Pay, we're happy to help via 0845 111 4455.

Sage Pay Support